# Axios - Redirect to controller with data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

i'm trying to redirect to Controller with data and use that data in controller ( i'm using laravel)

```
/* html */

<a @click="Submit()" href="/buy" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary btn-checkout-pay">Buy</a>

/*js codes*/
            Submit : function(){
                axios.post('/buy',{
                    ProductId : this.id,
                    //ProductId : "1";//
                    ProductAmount : this.temporaryamount
                    //ProductAmount : "12000";//
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        window.location = "/buy";
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
```

and the `/buy` is redirected to `ShoppingController@create`

```
/* web.php */
Route::get('/buy','ShoppingController@create');
Route::post('/buy','ShoppingController@create');
```

```
/* ShoppingController@create */

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
         dd($request['ProductId']);

    }
```

the problem is `$request['ProductId'];` is `null`

that means axois request is redirected without the **data**

P.S : i don't wan't to return the data i wanna just use the data in controller

Comment: add your route plz and give data in your .vue

Comment: Try `dd($request->ProductId);` instead

Comment: not possible "dd", do you need `return $request['ProductId']` and in your .vue `console.log(response);` but remove your `window.location` for see your log in console! And in router remove get!

Comment: remove this  window.location = "/buy";  you are getting your dd data in ajax call but when u r getting data you are  window.location = "/buy"; doing that

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly your problem is that you don't see the return of "dd".

It's normal your console.log is after the window! and no dd with axios! you have to return to see the answer!

Controller

```
 public function create(Request $request)
{
     return $request['ProductId'];
}
```

.vue

```
/*js codes*/
        Submit : function(){
            axios.post('/buy',{
                ProductId : this.id,
                //ProductId : "1";//
                ProductAmount : this.temporaryamount
                //ProductAmount : "12000";//
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //Remove window.location, or if you dont remove you dont see console.log!
                    //window.location = "/buy";

                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }
```

and on your route remove get.

```
/* web.php */
Route::post('/buy','ShoppingController@create');
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot used together those two create functions with  different route method and at the same time you want to get the product id. Your post request will work on that situation but the get request will not. that's why  dd($request['ProductId']) is null. You cannot use request as a parameter whenever you use a get request. $request as a parameter is for post request only.

for further explanation please read laravel docs [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)

so to solve your problem, you may remove this line

```
window.location = "/buy";
```

and show your post data in the controller by this

```
public function create(Request $request) {
   dd($request->all())
}
```